# Approximated (unsorted) square from a set of values

Tags: code-golf, math, array

So a colleaque came with this problem lately and I want to challange you to solve the problem in the code-golf style, shortest solution in any language wins.

**The Problem:**

Given is a random set of values, where the values themselfs are 
not the concern, but the amount (which is random as well)of values.

To keep the posts readable, let's limit the amount of values to 200, but the program must be able to handly any amount of values, which the language supports.

**Input:**
No Input needet, due the programm should set an random amount of values (limited to 200).

**Output:**
Can be text or graphic(px)
I recommend to use single digits as values if you use text based output, to keep the output clear.

**Example:**

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}   -- Amount : 16
```

Now you should sort these values in a approcimated square matrix like:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
(4 x 4)
```

Pretty simple so far, if not boring.

**But now the challange:**

The number of fields in the matrix must be equivalent to the amount of values given.
No empty fields or ignored values are allowed.

As an example, with 12 values, an square matrix is not possible, so you have to find the next aproximitation to it, which is 3x4 or 4x3 but NOT 4x4.

For any prime, the matrix would be **1 x prime**

**Examples:**

For 12 Values:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
X X X X   <- NOT ALLOWED, it makes the matrix square, but inserts non existing values.
```

or

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
1 2 3
```

For 35 Values:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8 9 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: You should give more details about the values. Are they continues ? How is `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` sorted ? How does the input look like ? What are the ways of input.

Comment: As I already wrote, the're not sorted and the values themself are not the concern. You could use strings as well, if you want to.

Comment: Can you improve your examples by properly stating what is input and what is output ?

Comment: Is the question "Find the factor of a natural number which is closest to its square root?" or is there more to it than that? It's tagged [tag:sorting] but the title implies that there's no need to sort. I am confused.

Comment: Basicly no, but I don't think we always have to do brain-breaking gigaquests.

Comment: @Sempie Not sure what you mean by "no input needed". Do you just mean the input should be hardcoded into the program?

Comment: What do you need input for? Both, amount of values and values should be random.

Comment: What is the point of the values if they aren't used? `X`'s would serve just as well.

Comment: @Sempie Ah I see. I somehow read "random" as "arbitrary".

Comment: Uhm yeah indeed. This quest is a job my colleage had to solve, where the values had been a concern. You're right, here they're not.

Comment: Side-Question: I noticed that an algorithm to solve this problem will find primes. Is there actual a better way to find primes?

Comment: If the program defines the list itself, it could simply print an arbitrary valid result without bothering about the input. I could always argue, the output corresponds to the random (non existing) input, the program thought of.

Comment: Well if you want this challenge to survive it would be best to rephrase is without the values. They distract from the main goal which as PeterTaylor said is simply to "Find the factor of a natural number which is closest to its square root?" That only needs a few sentences, and may have been done before.

Comment: And there are many better ways of [generating primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) than looping over all the numbers below the square root.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 91 bytes

```
n=RandomInteger@199+1
TableForm@Partition[Range@9~RandomChoice~n,Divisors@n~Nearest~Sqrt@n]
```

I hope I got this right:

- Generate a random length between `1` and `200` (inclusive).
- Generate a list of that length with numbers from `1` to `9` (inclusive).
- Find one of the two divisors closest to the square root, with `Divisors@n~Nearest~Sqrt@n`.
- Break the list into rows of that length.
- Display the grid with `TableForm`.

Example run:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Javasript, <s>156 or 119</s> 152 or 115

Output numbers 1 to 9: **152**

```
for(q=~~Math.sqrt(n=new Date%200);~~(w=n/q)!=w;--q);i=q=0;alert("".replace.call(Array(n+1),/./g,function(){return(++q>9?q=1:q)+(++i==w?i=0||"\n":" ")}))
```

Output zeroes: **115**

```
for(q=~~Math.sqrt(n=new Date%200);~~(w=n/q)!=w;--q);alert(Array(q+1).join("".replace.call(Array(w+1),/./g,0)+"\n"))
```